# ToList method doesn't show up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the `ToList` method; it doesn't show up after Blogs (Properties), but I want to see it.

What should I do? Please help me

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Blogs.);
}
```

Comment: `using System.Linq`, assuming `db.Blogs` is an object that can use the method.

Comment: What is db.Blogs? For some types you need to insert a .Cast<sometype>() before you can ToList() them..

Comment: without knowing db.Blogs the duplicate is meaningless!

Comment: In C# 7 and Visual Studio 2017, if you type in the `.ToList()` method, in Visual Studio should give a notice to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: No. Try with `dataGridView1.Rows..`. Not all things are Enumerable!

Comment: @Ghost: It looks like you never ever respond to comments asking you for clarifications. This is very rude behaviour. Sure, the crazy number of downvotes on your 1st question was also rude but that is no excuse. You ask, you wait & watch for at least an hour and you respond to the folks who try to help you in a timely manner, ie asap, answering all questions sent to you !!!

Comment: @TaW: Thanks for your comment But Idon't understand what comments I never ever respond what did you mean?

Comment: What is `db.Blogs` ???

Answer (score 3):

Try importing the `System.Linq` reference:

```
using System.Linq

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Blogs.ToList());
}
```